# rsync include-from file recursion

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rsync

I want to get only new or changed file list with few filters on result.
My all new or changed files are:

```
>f+++++++++ dsadcache.txt
>f+++++++++ root.svn
>f+++++++++ txt-file-in-root.txt
>fcsT...... wp-config.php
cd+++++++++ cache/
>f+++++++++ cache/fileincac.txt
>f+++++++++ cache/fileincache.txt
>f+++++++++ wp-content/inside.svn
>f+++++++++ wp-content/inside.txt
>f+++++++++ wp-content/object-cache.php
```

Final result should looks like:

```
>f+++++++++ txt-file-in-root.txt
>fcsT...... wp-config.php   
>f+++++++++ wp-content/inside.txt
```

When i try to include-from file with this rules:

```
- *cache*
+ *.html
+ *.txt
+ *.js
+ *.php
+ *.jpg
+ *.jpeg
+ *.png
+ *.bmp
+ *.gif
+ *.tif
+ *.tiff
+ *.ico
+ *.json
+ *.xml
- *
```

filters work but the result is not recursive

```
>f+++++++++ txt-file-in-root.txt
>fcsT...... wp-config.php
```

missing:

```
>f+++++++++ wp-content/inside.txt
```

My command is:

```
 rsync -nrci  --include-from="file" source/ destination
```

EDIT:

Let me explain the winning answer:

Here is the order of paths rsync process:

```
 dsadcache.txt
 txt-file-in-root.txt
 cache/
 cache/fileincac.txt
 cache/fileincache.txt
 wp-content/
 wp-content/inside.txt   
 wp-config.php
```

Without including

```
filter='+ */'
```

directories

```
cache/
wp-content/
```

are excluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recursive mode rsync visits subdirectories from the top down, so `wp-content` is matched against your rules first when rsync checks the top level of your tree. As there is no inclusion pattern that matches this directory, the generic exclusion rule `- *` drops it.

According to rsync manpage, one way of achieving your goal is to place a `+ */` anywhere before the exclusion rule, so subdirectories are included during recursive operation.

Comment: Check my edit, is that the right way of processing? :)

Comment: @NovkovskiStevoBato I just added wp-content/ as an excluded directory in your explanation (peer review pending). Other than that it looks correct to me.